# How to update rich-faces library version?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, richfaces

In my maven-project there are three dependencies corresponding to `RichFaces`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.richfaces.framework</groupId>
    <artifactId>richfaces-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.richfaces.framework</groupId>
    <artifactId>richfaces-impl</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.richfaces.ui</groupId>
    <artifactId>richfaces-ui</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And in the root of my eclipse project MavenDependencies branch contains `richfaces-api/ui/core -3.3.3`. How can I change the pom to upload latest available version? The thing is there is no version defined anywhere in the `pom`.

Answer (score 1):

There has to be a version defined otherwise it would not work. Eclipse will tell you what version you're using and where to find the definition if you hover over the dependency.

Answer (score 1):

I Think there's a bom dependency somehwere in your pom such as this

```
              <dependency>  
                <groupId>org.richfaces</groupId>  
                <artifactId>richfaces-bom</artifactId>  
                <version>BOM-VERSION</version>  
                <scope>import</scope>  
                <type>pom</type>  
            </dependency>
```

Update the BOM-VERSION part to something new such as "4.3.7.Final".